Keras Deep Learning Getting Error while Training Phase
I am a newbie in Deep Learning and I am trying to train a Deeplearning Model using the Keras Guide: https://keras.io/guides/keras_cv/object_detection_keras_cv/
The Problem I am facing is that at the end of Epoch I am getting the following error

`TypeError: Exception encountered when calling Pad.call().
Failed to convert elements of tf.RaggedTensor(values=tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("yolov8_detector_1/functional_1_1/rescaling_1/Add:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32,your text device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0), row_splits=Tensor("cond/Identity_2:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)), row_splits=Tensor("cond/Identity_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
Arguments received by Pad.call():
x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
constant_values=None`

The Snippet causing the error
 coco_metrics_callback = keras_cv.callbacks.PyCOCOCallback(val_ds,\
                                                              bounding_box_format="xywh")
    early_sasving = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('/kaggle/working/yolo.weights.h5', verbose=1, save_weights_only=True ,\
                                                 monitor='ciou',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
    early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='ciou', patience=10)

    
    INITIAL_LR = 0.007 * BATCH_SIZE / 16
    EPOCHS = 20
    LEARNING_RATE = keras.optimizers.schedules.CosineDecay(
        INITIAL_LR,
        decay_steps=EPOCHS * 2124,
    )
    
    GLOBAL_CLIPNORM = 10.0
    
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
        learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
        global_clipnorm=GLOBAL_CLIPNORM,
    )
    
    
    backbone = keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Backbone.from_preset(
        "yolo_v8_s_backbone_coco"  # We will use yolov8 small backbone with coco weights
    )
    yolo = keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Detector(
        num_classes=len(class_mapping),
        bounding_box_format="xywh",
        backbone=backbone,
        fpn_depth=1,
    )
    
    yolo.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, classification_loss="binary_crossentropy", box_loss="ciou"
    )
    yolo.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=test_ds,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        callbacks=[coco_metrics_callback,early_stopping,early_sasving],
    )

The Dataset link
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/featurefound/millitaryaccetsod
Code Link
https://www.kaggle.com/code/featurefound/keras-yolo-od/script
Also this script fails to run on TPU. Any help in the correct direction will be gr8.
I have tried multiple things but non have worked
